# apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Tags: apache-httpd, google-cloud

```
root@cloudshell:~$ service apache2 start
Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2AH00558: apache2: Could not
    reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using
    172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress
    this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

`access.log`, `error.log`, and  `other_vhosts_access.log` are empty

Answer (score 3):

If you insert the directive

```
ServerName {your server's fully qualified domain name}
```

in either httpd.conf or apache2.conf in /etc/apache2 and restart apache the warning message will disappear.

I also see the message:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

Do you have another web server running?  Something else is using port 80 and making this instance of Apache unhappy.

Comment: well i need to see about that, by the way thanks for it,

Comment: i m doing this in google cloud shell

Answer (score 0):

Add a line to your fully qualified hostname to the apache configuration:

```
LINE='ServerName www.example.com'
FILE='/etc/apache2/apache2.conf'
grep -qF -- "$LINE" "$FILE" || echo "$LINE" >> "$FILE"
service apache2 restart
```

If your server has no domain, use `localhost` instead.

About "Address already in use", probably you have another webserver already running.